# Decryption in PCL project in xamarin application

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I am developing an application using xamarin.android, xamarin.ios and windows phone 8.1 silver light. I am using an encrypted data and want to decrypt data in PCL project. For encryption AesCryptoServiceProvider class has been used. I want to decrypt my data in PCL project but not found any library for doing this. The above mentioned class is worked well in Android and ios project but I am not be able to use in windows phone project. Any help regarding this is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection/IoC is your friend. Basically you would implement an interface in PCL and implement it at OS level with whatever type is there that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PCL Crypto](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto).  It probably supports the functionality you need.